# Which ubuntu to install on a hercules ecafe ex HD with arm cortex A8 in order to be able to use skype's tools?

Tags: installation

I have purchased a Hercules ecafé ex HD which runs on ubuntu, but I can't install skype with this version. Could you advise me which OS from linux I can install to be able to use skype's functions and how?
I'm a real beginner in linux's world but I think I will like it!

Thanks a lot for your answords :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that Skype has released a version of the Skype telephone software for Arm CPU and Linux? 
If not, no one but Skype can release such a version. Because the program Skype isn't  free software, no one else can do that. This is one of the problems with non free software that doesn't follow any standards.
There are a couple of SIP telephone softwares available though. Software that are free and follows standards. You could try one of those.